# XSD first contract - WCF Soap Web service

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio, xsd, wsdl

I'm creating a Web Service using Visual Studio (2012). I don't want to bother with creating the WSDL manually, but I'd really like to be able to specify some of the types (or maybe all) using XSD, since it enables me to restrict certain elements (ex. require that an element is present).

How can I do this so that the resulting autogenerated WSDL use my XSD (with the same constraints)?

The purpose is to make the interface (the WSDL) as accurate as possible (more accurate than an interface in C# can be).

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could use [WSCF.Blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) to generate WSDL (and service) from and XSD. In practice WCF runtime will not support all constraints that you can put inside XSD. So your best bet is to use plain WCF data contracts and use the constraints that WCF allows you. For example:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public int i;
```

Comment: I tried using this constraint, but it did not change the XSD (the element is still nillable). WSCF.Blue looks nice (I had already had a look on it) - but it doesn't support VS 2012